# Saving an audio file in the database as a BLOB or in the file system?

Tags: php, android, android-sqlite, android-mediarecorder, blobstorage

I'm writing an application that one of the function is to allow a user to record a short phrases and listen them at the later time. Once recorded, an audio track suppose to be sent over the internet and store in the server. My questions is what is the best way of storing the audio in the android application and in the server as well. I thought about storing it in the SQLite database as a blob in android side and then make a HTTP request to run a php script in the server that will insert also a blob in the external database. Or should I store the files in the file system in both client and server sides and in the databases only keep the references to the files? Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: How large are the files - retrieving BLOBs from SQLite in Android is limited to byte[] arrays - so large files will be problematic on low memory devices.

Comment: Most of the time recordings shouldn't be longer than 10 sec which gives me about 20K in 3gp format. The longest recording might be about 5 mins

Comment: Ok, 5 ~ 600K or so fits in SQLite. How long do you intend to retain the recordings on the client? Permanently or just until you've synced with your server?

Comment: Just until a have synced with the server.

Comment: Hello Jens, I'm not sure if it's your comment beacause I can see part of it only in the inbox however it doesn't displays here in the page. Please finish your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've read in your question, there is no reason to send the files to your external server's database (unless you plan on listening to it... teehee).

It would be best to simply store the audio as an actual file on the User's SD card, then save a reference to the audio file in the SQLlitee database on the android phone. From what you've said, I don't see why you need the info on your external server's database, but you could also save the file's name, directory and ID in your external db.

You can store the audio in a BLOB in the SQLlite database, but beware, if the audio recording is too long, the file will be large, and you may run into trouble inserting and retrieving from the database. You could break the file into smaller 500KB sections and store them in the database, retrieve them according to their IDs, group them together and playback.

It would be unnecessary and ridiculous to transfer audio files back and forth between two different servers every time the user wants to record or playback a recording.

Comment: Actually there is a requirement and main point to store the files in the external server. Once a user record a voice he can listen it and then send it to the server. Therefore another user who run the application can also listen this track.